# Storing Data Azure Iot Central

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-edge, azure-iot-central

can I access to the Iot Hub behind the Azure Iot Central? I need to use:

1. IoT Edge feature
2. Device Provisioning
3. Get to Event-Hub Endpoint to process data

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Azure IoT Central has evolved since many of these answers were posted.

Today, IoT Central IoT Edge Support is preview and the Device Templates are in place to support it.

For the original data access requirement, use the [continuous data export](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-central/preview/howto-export-data)  feature in Azure IoT Central to export your data to Azure Event Hubs, Azure Service Bus, or Azure Blob storage instances.

Answer (score 0):

Azure IoT Central is a fully managed solution, you can't access underlying services including Azure IoT Hub. They are not exposed.

Reference ["Compare Azure IoT Central and Azure IoT options"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-central/overview-iot-options).

What you can do is device connection. You can send device-to-cloud message and update device twin.

Reference ["Device connectivity in Azure IoT Central"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-central/concepts-connectivity).

Compare to Azure IoT Central, Azure IoT solution accelerators(original name: Azure IoT Suite) gives you more control of the underlying services. You have access to the underlying Azure services to manage them, or replace them as needed. For your use case, you can consider [Azure IoT solution accelerators](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/features/iot-accelerators/).

Answer (score 0):

your requirement '*3. Get to Event-Hub Endpoint to process data*' can be done using your IoT Central App feature such as **Continuous Data Export** to the Event Hub.

The other way is to obtain an internal IoT Hub access to the events default endpoint from your IoT Central application access token like is shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53775213/sending-cloud-to-device-message-for-devices-provisoned-through-iot-central).

This approach allows to obtain an *eventhubSasToken* like is shown in the following code snippet:

```
"eventhubSasToken": {
    "sasToken": "SharedAccessSignature sr=sb%3A%2F%2Fep-ns-saas-ep-15-262-xxxxxxxxxx.servicebus.windows.net%2Fep-ehub-saas-iothu-1044564-xxxxxxxxxx&sig=xxxxxx&se=1546197703&skn=service",
    "entityPath": "ep-ehub-saas-iothu-1044564-xxxxxxxxxx",
    "hostname": "sb://ep-ns-saas-ep-15-262-xxxxxxxxxx.servicebus.windows.net/"
}
```

Comment: Yes Roman you are right about Continuous Data Export which now exports data to your Event Hub in your own Azure Subscription. The second approach using the IoT Central access token with the IoT Hub APIs is not recommended as the access token format may change and thus this should not be taken as a dependency. The access token was intended for the IoT Central Explorer CLI only (learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-central/…). We are currently working on an API for IoT Central to enable scenarios like this one.

Answer (score 0):

1. IoT Edge is not supported in IoT Central. If you would like to request this feature, please add it to [UserVoice](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/911455-azure-iot-central) and describe your use case.
2. Device Provisioning Service is supported in IoT Central. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-central/concepts-connectivity
3. While there is no way to access the underlying services, you can export your data using [Continuous Data Export](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-central/howto-export-data-event-hubs-service-bus) to your own Event Hub endpoint in your own Azure subscription. From there you can process the data how you like.