# Sending Cloud-To-Device message for devices provisoned through IoT-central

Tags: azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-central

I have been reading the documentation of this new SaaS offering, but I do not see any mention about being able to send a message to the device, eg: to **switch ON/OFF an equipment**.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-central/tutorial-add-device

I do see there is a provision to change the settings of the device, by being able to alter device-twin.

Also, I read there is a way to send an "echo" to the device. But, these don't serve my exact purpose.

So, is there a way I can send a C2D message, using the connection-string, which can be built using the routine-?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-central/tutorial-add-device#prepare-the-client-code

I would like to send this C2D through an AzureFunction, but it would be good to know if this can be somehow integrated into the IoT-Central UI.

Any other inputs to achieve my requirement (**switch ON/OFF an equipment**) would be a great help too!

Comment: have a look at https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-iothub-extension this AF output binding extension allows to send a C2D message, see its implementation method SendCloudToDeviceMessageAsync.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am just trying to understand bit more. With my above connection string(which is device-connection-string), will I be able to send a C2D message? because the samples I see generally use service-connection-string hence they dint work for me.

Comment: You are right, the Azure IoT Central didn't give you an access to the internal IoT Hub service-facing endpoint. This side is managed only by IoT-Central such as Data Export, Application Builder, Analytics, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An API is now available to achieve this:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/iotcentral/devices/executecomponentcommand

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)

Answer (score 3):

As I mentioned in my comment, the Azure IoT Central has a full control over the internal IoT Hub service-facing endpoint. However, there is a way, where the Azure IoT Central allows a limited access to this service-facing endpoint and using a REST API to handle a device twin and invoking a Direct Method on the device.

The following are steps how to obtain a sas token for authorization header needed for REST Api calls:

1. Get the Access Token from your Azure IoT Central application.

   the format is:

   ```
   SharedAccessSignature sr=appId&sig=xxxxx&skn=myTokenName&se=1577730019340
   ```

   Note, that the *appId* is showing an application id of your Azure IoT Central application
2. Call the REST POST request to obtain an *iothubTenantSasToken.sasToken*

   ```
   POST https://api.azureiotcentral.com/v1-beta/applications/{appId}/diagnostics/sasTokens  
   Authorization:SharedAccessSignature sr=appId&sig=xxxxx&skn=myTokenName&se=1577730019340
   ```

   The response has the following format:

   ```
   {
     "iothubTenantSasToken": {
       "sasToken": "SharedAccessSignature sr=saas-iothub-xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx.azure-devices.net&sig=xxxxx&se=1546197703&skn=service"
       },
     "eventhubSasToken": {
       "sasToken": "SharedAccessSignature sr=sb%3A%2F%2Fep-ns-saas-ep-15-262-xxxxxxxxxx.servicebus.windows.net%2Fep-ehub-saas-iothu-1044564-xxxxxxxxxx&sig=xxxxxx&se=1546197703&skn=service",
       "entityPath": "ep-ehub-saas-iothu-1044564-xxxxxxxxxx",
       "hostname": "sb://ep-ns-saas-ep-15-262-xxxxxxxxxx.servicebus.windows.net/"
       },
     "expiry": 1546197703
   }
   ```
3. The sasToken for our service-facing endpoint calls is:

   ```
   SharedAccessSignature sr=saas-iothub-xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx.azure-devices.net&sig=xxxxx&se=1546197703&skn=service
   ```

Now, we can use some Azure IoT Hub REST APIs, basically the calls with the *twins* in the uri path, such as:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/iothub/service/gettwin

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/iothub/service/updatetwin

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/iothub/service/replacetwin

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/iothub/service/invokedevicemethod

Example for invoking a Direct Method on the device1:

```
POST https://saas-iothub-xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx.azure-devices.net/twins/device1/methods?api-version=2018-06-30
Authorization:SharedAccessSignature sr=saas-iothub-xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx.azure-devices.net&sig=xxxxx&se=1546197703&skn=service

body:
    {
      "methodName": "writeLine",
      "timeoutInSeconds": 20,
      "payload": {
         "input1": 12345,
         "input2": "HelloDevice"
         }
    }
```

Example of updating a device twin tags property:

```
PATCH https://saas-iothub-xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx.azure-devices.net/twins/device1?api-version=2018-06-30
Authorization:SharedAccessSignature sr=saas-iothub-xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx.azure-devices.net&sig=xxxxx&se=1546197703&skn=service

body:
    {
      "tags": {
        "test":12345
        }
    }
```

Note, that the sasToken *expiry* time is 60 minutes. I do recommend to cache the response object from the step 2. and refreshing based on the expiry time.

**UPDATE:**

The following are steps for using an IoT Central access token for handling a device twins and device direct method within the azure function.

4. Generate an access token in your IoT Central application, see the following screen snippet:

[image]

5. Add this access token to your function application settings. In this example, the *App Setting Name* is used *AzureIoTCAccessToken*. Note, that this access token can be stored in the Azure Key Vault, see more details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-key-vault-references).
6. Create HttpTrigger function in your Function App.
7. Replace run.csx with the following code:

   ```
   #r "Newtonsoft.Json"
   #r "Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http"

   using System.Net;
   using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
   using Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives;
   using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
   using Newtonsoft.Json;
   using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
   using System.Linq;
   using System.Text;

   // reusable client proxy
   static HttpClientHelper iothub = new HttpClientHelper(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AzureIoTCAccessToken"));

   public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(HttpRequest req, ILogger log)
   {
       log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

       var atype = new { device = new { deviceId = "", properties = new JObject(), measurements = new JObject() } };
       var iotcobj = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(await req.ReadAsStringAsync(), atype);

       // get deviceId, for test puspose use the device1
       string deviceId = iotcobj?.device?.deviceId ?? "device1";

       // get a device twins
       var response = await iothub.Client.GetAsync($"/twins/{deviceId}?api-version=2018-06-30");
       string jsontext = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
       log.LogInformation($"DeviceTwin: {JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsontext)}");

      // patch on desired property
      var patch = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { properties = new { desired = new { ping = DateTime.UtcNow } } });
      response = await iothub.Client.PatchAsync($"/twins/{deviceId}?api-version=2018-06-30", new StringContent(patch, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
      jsontext = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
      log.LogInformation($"Patch: {JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsontext)}");

      // invoke a device method
      var method = new { methodName = "writeLine", timeoutInSeconds = 30, payload = new {input1 = 12345, input2 = "HelloDevice" } };
      response = await iothub.Client.PostAsJsonAsync($"/twins/{deviceId}/methods?api-version=2018-06-30", method );
      jsontext = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
      log.LogInformation($"DirectMethod: {JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsontext)}");

      return new OkObjectResult(jsontext);      
   }

   class HttpClientHelper
   {
       HttpClient client;
       string accessToken;
       dynamic iothub;
       long toleranceInSeconds = 60;

       public HttpClientHelper(string accessToken)
       {
           this.accessToken = accessToken;
           this.iothub = GetIoTHubTenant(accessToken);
           string hostname = GetHostNameFromSaSToken(this.iothub.iothubTenantSasToken.sasToken);
           client = new HttpClient() { BaseAddress = new Uri($"https://{hostname}") };
           client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", iothub.iothubTenantSasToken.sasToken);
       }
       public HttpClient Client
       {
           get
           {
               if((new DateTime(1970, 1, 1)).AddSeconds(this.iothub.expiry - toleranceInSeconds) < DateTime.UtcNow)
                   SetAuthorizationHeader();
               return client;
           }
       }
       private void SetAuthorizationHeader()
       {
           lock (client)
           {
               if ((new DateTime(1970, 1, 1)).AddSeconds(this.iothub.expiry - toleranceInSeconds) < DateTime.UtcNow)
               {
                   if (client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Contains("Authorization"))
                       client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Remove("Authorization");
                   this.iothub = GetIoTHubTenant(this.accessToken);
                   client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", this.iothub.iothubTenantSasToken.sasToken);
               }
           }
       }
       private string GetHostNameFromSaSToken(string sastoken)
       {
           var parts = sastoken.Replace("SharedAccessSignature", "").Split(new[] { '&' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(s => s.Split(new[] { '=' }, 2)).ToDictionary(x => x[0].Trim(), x => x[1].Trim());
           return parts["sr"] ?? "";
       }

       private dynamic GetIoTHubTenant(string iotcAccessToken)
       {
           string appId = GetHostNameFromSaSToken(iotcAccessToken);
           using (var hc = new HttpClient())
           {
               hc.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", accessToken);
               string address = $"https://api.azureiotcentral.com/v1-beta/applications/{appId}/diagnostics/sasTokens";
               var response = hc.PostAsync(address, new StringContent("{}", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")).Result;
               return JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result, new { iothubTenantSasToken = new { sasToken = "" }, expiry = 0L });
           }
       }
   }
   ```

**Note:**, The above implementation is based on the generated access token by your IoT Central application like it has been recently released for general availability, see [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-iot-central-ga/). In the case of the changing a format, etc. all clients, testers, etc. included the above solution will be impacted.

Comment: Thank you Roman for pursuing this so far for me, appreciate it. Can you please also outline how I can get the "Access Token" in your step-1. Are you getting this from  the DPS SDK or dps-keygen? Because what I see is just this data as in this picture. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-central/media/concepts-connectivity/device-connect.png Please advice.

Comment: Go to your IoT Central Application Administration page to generate this access token and remember it for usage.

Comment: Note, that this access token (its parts such as  sr,sig, skn and se) can be added to the azure function via a url query string when you configure callback url of the action webhook. Once we have this access token in the AF, we can follow step 2. and 3. to obtain a limited access to the internal iot hub service-facing endpoint.

Comment: Thank you Roman for answering in such detail. While the method you describe works at this time, this is not recommended as the access token format may change and thus this should not be taken as a dependency. The access token was intended for the IoT Central Explorer CLI only (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-central/howto-use-iotc-explorer). We are currently working on an API for IoT Central to enable scenarios like this one.

Answer (score 2):

For your specific use case, the only way to do this today is to [trigger a Logic App workflow using its HTTP endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-http-endpoint#call-or-trigger-logic-apps-through-http-endpoints) from the Azure Functions. In the Logic app, you can build a workflow using the **Azure IoT Central connector** that updates device properties and settings.

We are working on APIs in IoT Central that can light up use cases like yours, so stay tuned!

Comment: I've been trying out the IoT Central connector (Preview) in a Logic App to run a command on the device. It's easy enough to select a device template and command, and grab the deviceId from an input parameter in the POST which is the trigger, but when I look at the run history it has failed with a 404 under OUTPUTS. Looking at Show raw inputs reveals a path which might be correct: "path": "/applications/7270478a-e128-4b1c-8b09-e148f78893f1/devices/jeffsdeskjune/commands/sendmsg". I don't know what the problem is.

Comment: @AlbertoVega-MSFT In a way. By turning on Continuous Data Export and capturing the device feed from that I can create a map from well-known deviceid (aka device name, registration name) to internal-only-iotc-knows-it-afaik-device-id, and use the latter with the IOTC Connector to send a command to the device (because the former doesn't work). I don't know whether this can be relied on going forward but it works right now. We are meeting with some MSFT people on Monday to discuss.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using **Settings** there is a setting type called "Toggle". In order to implement it, you can go to your IoT Central Application from the Azure Portal. Then:

- Go to Device Explorer tab
- Select a device
- Click on the "Settings" tab for the device
- Click on the "Edit Template" Button located on the upper right corner
- Under "Library" find and click on "Toggle"

[image]

- Enter the settings for the toggle functionality

[image]

**If you are looking into doing it at scale** you could [Create and Run a Job](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-central/howto-run-a-job)

In IoT Central you can manage your connected devices at scale using jobs. The jobs functionality enables you to perform bulk updates to device properties, settings, and commands.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Although it's one way to execute commands, its not helpful for me to send any particular data to the device. But more importantly, I needed it to be run from an external application. I am not sure if these jobs can be executed from an Azure function? Also it's not really feasible to create a job for each device where my requirement is to control individual devices separately.